# How to secure credentials for open source crowdsource software?

Tags: security, github, open-source, credentials

We are developing open source benchmarking software that users can download, execute on their system (which runs some benchmarks for some stuff) and then uploads the results to a central database. Those anonymous, crowdsourced benchmark results are then displayed on a website for everyone to see.

A big feature of this software is that it's open source. It will be hosted on GitHub and will include instructions for anyone to download and compile the source themselves, for peace-of-mind or whatever just incase people don't trust our program.

But we obviously cannot divulge the security credentials that allows the software to upload benchmark results to our central database. So we aren't going to include these in the public source.

So people could compile the software themselves (which is good) and use it, but it would be useless because the software wouldn't be able to upload to the database, which is the entire purpose of the crowdsourcing software. So users would be forced to use "our build" of the software that has credentials hidden away inside. Many people are smart enough to not bother with unfamiliar .exe's these days, so that doesn't help the situation. Also, since the source is open, anyone could modify it, compile it and distribute with malicious intent, saying that it's our software.

How do you get around this problem of security credentials in open source software? Obviously rule #1 is you don't include it in the distributed source. But if the credentials are required for the software to function as intended, then what do you do? We want to keep it open source so that users have a reason to trust the software.

Comment: this should be a wiki, at least

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for each project owner to register into your site, create a public/private key pair for them and use an asymmetric encryption for identify your results source